# Cannot connect wireless internet with 12.10 on Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: wireless, 12.10, dell

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my **Dell Inspiron 1525** laptop. Wired network connection works a treat but there is no option to `Enable Wireless Networking`. Nor can I use `Edit Connections` to add a wireless network connection. After entering details, the <kbd>Save</kbd> button is disabled.

Comment: If i get you right: Wired connection works perfect, but wireless is not. Well, if I may ask, Have you installed the drivers for the wireless device? If so, did you install the Ubuntu package of the driver (perhaps .deb) or you installed the installer .exe (perhaps via wine)? By default, Ubuntu should work with a whole lot of ranges of devices. But that isn't 100% certain.

Answer (score 2):

I used this laptop with ubuntu 10.04 two years ago.For using Wi-Fi, you must open the Software Sources and then open the tab "Additional Drivers", probably you can see the Wi-Fi driver for your Dell.Activate it and connect a wireless network.
Or run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After that restart computer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, tried the same thing as suggested by Hckr and Matthias (Although found it unnecessary to follow through with most of that) and got it done super quick.

If you find you get an error that bcmwl-kernel-source can't be found/installed try using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I know that seems a little simple, but thought i'd save people the confusion. Run that then try Hckr's initial command again and restart after downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo modprobe brcmsmac`. That, by itself, fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Following steps helped me to solve the problem:

- first I needed to install the sta driver for wireless network:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
  ```
- next install the b43 firmware with the installer:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```
- next step you need to add a line above the `exit 0` in /etc/rc.local

  I used leafpad, but you can use actually any kind of editor like gedit:

  ```
  gksu leafpad /etc/rc.local
  ```

  and add above `exit 0` `modprobe b43`
- finally to get your wireless running already in this session you need to type into the terminal

  ```
  sudo modprobe b43
  ```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no option to even Edit the Wireless Connection, the problem is probably that there is no wireless device driver available to Ubuntu.

WHY (if that is the problem): Because the device driver for this wireless chip set is proprietary and are not automatically included in Ubuntu.

HOW TO FIX: Easiest way (if you don't want to open a term) for 12.10 is to:

- click on the system settings
- click on "Software Sources"
- click on "Additional Drivers"

There you should see a list of alternative drivers, mainly Broadcom 802.11 wireless driver source from **bcmwl-kernel-source**. It's listed as proprietary.